# Как импортировать xml / yaml / csv в базу с товарами (прайс агрегаторы)

Tags: php, xml, laravel, csv, yaml

Добрый вечер. У меня возник такой вопрос. Вот как прайс агрегаторы импортируют в базу прайс листы магазинов?
Вот к примеру есть товар "Ноутбук Acer E1-572G" он в базе агрегатора под таким названием, и допустим у магазина в прайс листе этот же товар, но он по другому написан "Acer E1-572G (eu)" или так "Acer E1572G'. Как тогда агрегатор при загрузке прайс листа в базу, проверяет товар на наличие, и добавляет предложение магазина к товару?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По штрих коду сверяет товар при загрузке.

Comment: В инете стрих код реально найти? Не могу же я со всех товаров штрихкод брать

Comment: Если я тебя правильно понял у тебя стоит задача собираться с разных мест прайсы, обрабатывать их и при одинаковых товарах группировать. Так вот что бы группировать товар в нём должно быть что то общее, как правило это штрих код . Нужно что  бы прайс загружали с полем штрих. Правда напрашивается сразу вопрос, что делать с позицией по которой не прислали штрих код .

Comment: Да, вы правильно меня поняли. Мне вот интеиесно как яндекс маркет, хотлайн, прайс.ру это делуют...

Comment: Вот описание API Яндекс. Как вы можете заметит там есть коды идентификаторы. Код Яндекса присвоенного товару , штрих код и.т.д.[Яндекс API](https://yandex.ru/support/partnermarket/offers.xml)